# How to move the HorizontalScrollview to a desired position , i use the following instruction but don't work :

Tags: android, fragment, scrollto, horizontalscrollview

The HorizontalScrollView is in a Fragment why RUNNABLE use that advises people but still does not work.

```
public class AvailabilityHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {


public AvailabilityHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    inflate(context);
    find();

}

public AvailabilityHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    inflate(context);
    find();

}

private void inflate(Context context){
    inflate(context, R.layout.horizontal_scrollview_availability, this);
}

private void find() {
    availabilityLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hsa_container_ll);
}
private void scrollToCurrentReservation() {

    this.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
            public void run() {

                scrollTo(250,250);
                invalidate(); 

        }
    },250);
}
```

Here the CODE of the AvailabilityHorizontalScrollView intro the XML for Fragment:

```
<es.sw.bluemove.customview.AvailabilityHorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/fld_availability_sv"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_s"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </es.sw.bluemove.customview.AvailabilityHorizontalScrollView>
```

Here the CODE of "hsa_container_ll":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hsa_availability_sv"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_med"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hsa_container_ll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find finally my problem:

The view that contains Horizontal Layout has the property in xml VISIBLE = GONE; this make me crazy to find about to move horizontal scrollview to my desired position because it didn't move when the view make visible = true.

ScrollTo didn't work to me because view has property GONE, like i said. I changed the property to INVISIBLE and the instruction scrollTo works perfectly. The absence HorizontalScrollview was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to place Your `hsa_caontainer_ll` as root view in `.xml` file:

2. You need to add View after You inflate it

```
private void inflate(Context context){
    View inflated = inflate(context, R.layout.horizontal_scrollview_availability, this);
    addView(inflated);
}
```

After that You can find Your View via `findViewById()`

3. You cannot scroll Your ScrollView if Your LinearLayout is empty. Cause scrollable content width is 0.